# Why my swiperjs carousel works in localhost but not in production (e.g. using netlify or vercel)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, swiper.js, autoplay

This is my repository: [github](https://github.com/tobiajras/casacarina-one)
Netlify production: [netlify](https://casacarinaone.netlify.app/)

In my code I have modules of Pagination, that's works good. But autoplay module have a doesn't works

And when I go to other section and come back to home section autoplay start to work

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { Autoplay, Pagination, EffectCoverflow } from 'swiper';

// Import Swiper styles
import 'swiper/scss';
import 'swiper/scss/autoplay';
import 'swiper/scss/pagination';
import { carouselData } from '../../data/carouselData';

export default function CarouselSwiper() {
  return (
    <div className='carouselSwiper__parentDiv'>
      <Swiper
        className='carouselSwiper__Swiper'
        modules={[Autoplay, Pagination, EffectCoverflow]}
        slidesPerView={1}
        autoplay={{ delay: 2500, disableOnInteraction: false }}
        pagination={{
          clickable: true,
        }}
        loop={true}
        speed={500}
      >
        {carouselData.map(({ id, title, src }) => {
          return (
            <SwiperSlide key={id}>
              <img
                className='carouselSwiper__img'
                src={`assets/Fondos/${src}`}
                alt={title}
              />
            </SwiperSlide>
          );
        })}
      </Swiper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you find solution for this? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're experiencing the same issue, but I'm facing a problem with my Astro.js and Swiper.js site when deployed on Netlify. While Swiper works fine locally, I encountered a CORS error in the browser console when I deployed it on Netlify: 'Access to script at 'https://xxx/xxx.js' from origin 'https://xx/xxx.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'

I believe this issue is caused by Netlify's default 'Asset Optimization' setting, which automatically bundles JavaScript files, potentially causing them to be hosted on a domain that does not support CORS. Once I disabled this setting, the site worked as expected, similar to how it did locally.